# How to create a distributed suffix tree on HPC cluster

Tags: mpi, hpc

I want to create a suffix tree for 4 GB of input string. Ideally the size of tree in memory will be approx 100 GB. I can’t do this on a normal desktop. Is there any way to do it on windows HPC cluster? How can I distribute the suffix tree on different compute node of HPC?

Comment: What's the size of your cluster? 100 GB is still a lot of memory, perhaps you should consider writing some (most) of it to disk. Also, what will you be doing with this data?

Comment: Thanks for you reply suszterpatt.  Cluster is consist of 8 Nodes each with 24GB of RAM and 160 GB harddisk. I want to use this tree for Sequence matching. There will be millions of search for string matching. Writing on disk is not a option for me, its making search slow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to do this; Google Scholar lists [several papers](http://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q="distributed+memory"+"suffix+tree") on the topic.  The trick is in the initial assignment of partial suffixes to the initial processors; that has to be chosen so that each processor can go off and find it's section of the tree independantly.   Once that's done, the usual suffix-tree operations can be done fairly efficiently.   I don't know any public examples of implementations.